# How to get result from mysql database in sails rest service

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I am using http://sailsjs.com/ framework for creating rest services. I am using `mysql` database for which I have installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-mysql

> npm install sails-mysql

I have done below changes in `connections.js` and `models.js` in `config` directory to establish a connection with `mysql` database.

**connections.js**

```
mysql: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'books'
}
```

**models.js**

```
connection: 'mysql'
```

I have this `Books.js` model in `models` directory

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    id: 'integer',
    bookName: 'string',
    author: 'string',
    genre: 'string'
  }
};
```

I am not sure where I should fetch result of books database either in controller or in service ? Can anyone explain what is the way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is subjective, opinion-based.

My preference is to keep such methods in service.

Service methods can be called by different controller action.
In case the fetch logic is to be used only once, you may write it in controller as well.

PS: Complex controllers should be written using different service methods and some logic which is used only in that controller.

Comment: Thanks Do you have an links which can help me to understand how to create rest web service in sails and mysql database connectivity and CRUD operation